# PWA Add to Home Screen Popup Button is Not Working

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to add popup button for download the Progressive Web Application(PWA) and add to home screen. Honestly I don't know where did i mistake.

```js
let deferredPrompt;
const addBtn = document.querySelector('#add');
addBtn.style.display = 'none';

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  deferredPrompt = e;
  addBtn.style.display = 'block';

  addBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    addBtn.style.display = 'block';
    deferredPrompt.prompt();

    deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
      if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
        console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
      } else {
        console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
      }
      deferredPrompt = null;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.add-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<button id="add">Add to home</button>
```

Comment: Do you have a working fetch handler in your service worker? Do you have a manifest? Do you run over https?

Comment: yes  manifest & service worker working fine add to home button also worked first time but I uninstall and try to install again..now its not working

Comment: how do you uninstalled it exactly?

Comment: Chrome got a popup message when it was finished installing. On that popup I saw the option to uninstall

Comment: In Chrome and Edge, if you have a qualified PWA you will see an install icon in the address bar. This should also trigger the beforeinstall prompt.

Also, set a break point in your code to make sure it is being run. That way you can step through and make sure variables are set correctly, etc.